# Multi-threaded powershell script on single processor system

Tags: multithreading, batch-file, powershell

I have access to a single-core single-processor VM with which to do logging for my team. I have the following code:

```
$sb = {
Param($_)

if($_.CONTROLLER -ne ".xx" ){
    $posIP = "10." + $_.IP + $_.CONTROLLER 
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $posIP -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        $mapPath = "\\" + $posIP + "\c$"
        net use $mapPath $password /user:$userName | Out-Null
        if(Test-Path $mapPath$dataFile) {
            [xml]$periods = Get-Content $mapPath$dataFile
            $endDate = $periods.IndataDbf.ingredient.PeriodDetail.PeriodEndDate | select -last 1
            $output = "$($_.STORE);$endDate" }
        else {
            $outPut = $_.STORE + ';' + "$dataFile Not Found" }
        net use $mapPath /de | Out-Null
    }
    else {
        $outPut = $_.STORE + ';' + "Map FAILED" }
    Write-Output $OutPut
}
}

Import-Csv $inFile | ForEach-Object { 
while ((Get-Job -State Running).Count -ge 100) {
   Start-Sleep -Seconds 5;
}
Write-Output $_.STORE
Start-Job -Scriptblock $sb -ArgumentList $_ | Write-Verbose
Get-Job -State Completed -HasMoreData 1 | Receive-Job | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outLog
}
Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job | Out-File -Append -FilePath $outLog
```

Which runs well, but takes the same amount of time as running the same code without `Start-Job` and just a loop. However, the previous logging command used BATCH files and automatically opened a couple dozen child command windows to process data, then return, and it runs in under half the time. The code used is the same, so I don't understand why adding more threads didn't make the script run faster. Can anyone tell me why a BATCH file program with a couple dozen child windows runs so much faster with arguably the same code? Any why does the `Start-Job` command not improve the speed at all? I would think it would try to execute multiple threads simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a lot of overhead when using start-job and whenever you use pipeline.
If you use runspaces instead it maybe faster.Take a look at http://newsqlblog.com/2012/05/22/concurrency-in-powershell-multi-threading-with-runspaces/

Comment: I'll have to look at that at home at some point. My employer blocks Box, so I can't download the code to look at how it's implemented, and the post has no full listing of the code.